# JavaScript. Promises in User Functions. Why does not it work?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, google-cloud-functions

Task: In the main function, call two functions, the first of which contains asynchronous methods.

In the ReadValueBalances function, the once () method returns Promise. Then I use then () and return the result.
After this, the second function UpdateValueMapBalances should be started.

But, why is UpdateValueMapBalances first performed first, rather than ReadValueBalances?

```
    'use strict';

// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const FBfunctions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();




exports.UpdateBalancesUser = FBfunctions.database.ref('/{userID}/Movements').onWrite((MoveDataChange, context) => {
    const UserID = String(context.params.userID);   
    const BalanceRef = admin.database().ref('/'+ UserID +'/Balances') ;

    var Date_first, Date_last;
    var Value_first = 0; 
    var Value_last = 0;

    var TypeofChange = 0;
    MoveDataChange.after.forEach((childMove) => {
        if (!childMove.exists()) {
            console.log('MoveDataChange.after: нет!');
            //return false;  //выходим из функции
        }
        Date_last = childMove.child('dateInMilisec').val();
        Value_last = childMove.child("value").val()*childMove.child("kind").val();  
        console.log('Date_last: ', Date_last, '. Value_last: ', Value_last);
        TypeofChange = TypeofChange +1;
        //return true;
    });

    MoveDataChange.before.forEach((childMove) => {
        if (!childMove.exists()) {
            console.log('MoveDataChange.before: нет!');
            //return false;  //выходим из функции
        }
        Date_first = childMove.child('dateInMilisec').val();
        Value_first = -childMove.child("value").val()*childMove.child("kind").val();    //с обратным знаком, т.к. его не стало
        console.log('Date_first: ', Date_first, '. Value_first: ', Value_first);
        TypeofChange = TypeofChange - 1;
        //return true;
    });

    console.log('TypeofChange: ', TypeofChange);

    if (TypeofChange < 0) {             // удалили движение
        Date_last = Date_first; 
        Value_last = 0;             
    }
    if (TypeofChange > 0) {             // новое движение
        Date_first = Date_last; 
        Value_first = Value_last;
        Value_last = 0;         
    }

    if (Date_first > Date_last) {      //меняем местами
        let Date_tmp = Date_first;
        Date_first = Date_last;
        Date_last = Date_tmp;
        let Value_tmp = Value_first;
        Value_first = Value_last;
        Value_last = Value_tmp;
    }


    let BalanceMap = new Map;
    let BalanceMapUpdate = new Map;
    return ReadValueBalances(Date_first, BalanceRef)
        .then(UpdateValueMapBalances(BalanceMap, Date_first, Date_last, Value_first, Value_last))
        .then((BalanceMapUpdate)=>{
            return BalanceRef.update(BalanceMapUpdate, ()=>{
                console.log('Записали изменения ', BalanceMapUpdate);
            })
        }); 
});

function ReadValueBalances(Date_1, BalanceRef){  
    var BalancesMap = new Map;
    return BalanceRef.orderByKey().startAt(String(Date_1)).once('value')      // считываем значения БД после даты записи движения
        .then((DataSnapShot)=>{
            console.log('ReadValueBalances Получили выгрузку от ', Date_1);
            if (!DataSnapShot.exists()) {                                       // если после даты ничего, то считываем последнее значение до даты движения
                console.log('ReadValueBalances Получаем последнюю запись');                     
                return BalanceRef.orderByKey().endAt(String(Date_1)).limitToLast(1).once('value');                  
            } 
            else {
                console.log('ReadValueBalances Выгрузка есть');
                return DataSnapShot;
            }
        })
        .then((DataSnapShot)=>{         
            DataSnapShot.forEach((snapshot)=>{                  // цикл по элементам выгрузки. записываем в Map
                BalancesMap.set(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
                console.log('snap key: ', snapshot.key, ' value:', snapshot.val());             
            });
            console.log('ReadValueBalances Закончили цикл');
            return BalancesMap;
        }); 
}


function UpdateValueMapBalances(BalanceMap_input, Date1, Date2, Delta1, Delta2){
    var BalanceMap_output = new Map;
    const Date_1 = new Date(Date1);
    const Date_2 = new Date(Date2); 
    console.log('UpdateValueMapBalances Date_1: ', Date_1, ' Date_2: ', Date_2);
    if (BalanceMap_input.size === 0) {
        console.log('UpdateValueMapBalances вх.коллекция пустая');
        var Date_item = new Date(Date_1);   
        console.log('UpdateValueMapBalances Date_item: ', Date_item);
        Date_item.setDate(1);
        Date_item.setMonth(Date_item.getMonth()+1);
        BalanceMap_output.set(Date_item.getMilliseconds(), Delta1);
        console.log('UpdateValueMapBalances BalanceMap_output: ', BalanceMap_output);
        return BalanceMap_output;
    }

    BalanceMap_input.forEach((ValueItem, KeyItem, MapItem)=>{
        console.log('ValueItem: ', ValueItem, ' KeyItem: ', KeyItem);   
        if (KeyItem <= Date1) {                 // возможно только в случае, если в выгрузке только 1 значение (до даты движения)
            console.log('UpdateValueMapBalances Дополняем коллекцию сверху');
            var bool_stop = false;
            var Date_item = new Date(KeyItem);                  
            Date_item.setDate(1); // на всякий случай
            console.log('Date_item ', Date_item);
            while (!bool_stop) {
                Date_item.setMonth(Date_item.getMonth()+1);
                if ((Date_item-Date_1) <= 0) {
                    BalanceMap_output.set(Date_item.getMilliseconds, ValueItem);    
                } else {
                    BalanceMap_output.set(Date_item.getMilliseconds, ValueItem + Delta1);  // в случае с удалением delta 1= -Value
                    bool_stop = true;
                }
            }
            console.log('UpdateValueMapBalances Дополнили коллекцию сверху');   
            return BalanceMap_output;  //TODO: выйти из цикла               
        } else {
            console.log('UpdateValueMapBalances Изменяем коллекцию снизу');             
            if (KeyItem <= Date2) {          // т.е. коллекция имеет значения после Date_first до Date_last. Срабатывает только если даты отличаются
                BalanceMap_output.set(KeyItem, ValueItem + Delta1);     
            } else {                                    // т.е. коллекция имеет значения после Date_last
                BalanceMap_output.set(KeyItem, ValueItem + Delta1 + Delta2);    // в случае с новым движением/удалением Delta2=0, а Delta1= -Value
            }
            console.log('UpdateValueMapBalances Изменили коллекцию снизу');
        }       
    })
    return BalanceMap_output;
```

Log:

```
2:23:26.362 PM
outlined_flag   
UpdateBalancesUser
Function execution took 1699 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
2:23:26.356 PM
info    
UpdateBalancesUser
Записали изменения Map { '1522540800000' => 200000 }
2:23:26.353 PM
info    
UpdateBalancesUser
ReadValueBalances Закончили цикл
2:23:26.353 PM
info    
UpdateBalancesUser
snap key: 1522540800000 value: 200000
2:23:26.353 PM
info    
UpdateBalancesUser
ReadValueBalances Выгрузка есть
2:23:26.352 PM
info    
UpdateBalancesUser
ReadValueBalances Получили выгрузку от 1519862400000
2:23:25.861 PM
info    
UpdateBalancesUser
UpdateValueMapBalances BalanceMap_output: Map { [Function: getMilliseconds] => -400000 }
2:23:25.860 PM
info    
UpdateBalancesUser
UpdateValueMapBalances Date_item: 2018-03-01T00:00:00.000Z
2:23:25.860 PM
info    
UpdateBalancesUser
UpdateValueMapBalances вх.коллекция пустая
2:23:25.860 PM
info    
UpdateBalancesUser
UpdateValueMapBalances Date_1: 2018-03-01T00:00:00.000Z Date_2: 2018-03-01T00:00:00.000Z
2:23:25.849 PM
info    
UpdateBalancesUser
TypeofChange: 0
2:23:25.849 PM
info    
UpdateBalancesUser
Date_first: 1519862400000 . Value_first: -400000
```

Comment: Can you try to obtain a smaller code that shows the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
 .then(UpdateValueMapBalances(BalanceMap, Date_first, Date_last, Value_first, Value_last))
```

Breaking it down, `then` expects a function as the argument https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

but what is happening instead is you are directly calling `UpdateValueMapBalances` and the return value from that is being used as the argument for `then`

Here it is written a slightly different way to illustrate:

```
const successFunction = UpdateValueMapBalances(BalanceMap, Date_first, Date_last, Value_first, Value_last);

...


.then(successFunction)
```

Wrapping that function call in another function will hopefully solve your problem, assuming you are passing all the right data around via arguments correctly. There is too much here for me to tell.

```
.then(() => UpdateValueMapBalances(BalanceMap, Date_first, Date_last, Value_first, Value_last)
```

Comment: Yes, the error is really in this line. I rewrote it like this:
.then((BalanceMap)=>{
 return UpdateValueMapBalances(BalanceMap, Date_first, Date_last, Value_first, Value_last)
  })

I hope this is correct